# Usar um operador em um switch case

Tags: c, switch

Se eu fizer, roda de boa:

```
#include <stdio.h>

int op1;
int main(){
scanf("%d", &op1);

 switch(op1) {
    case 1:
        puts("Hello World");
}

}
```

Eu queria fazer com que ao introduzir um carácter especial, por exemplo, +, -, / (etc), me mostra-se no caso, "Hello World" ao invés de ter que colocar 1. Tem como? 
Algo do género:

```
#include <stdio.h>

int op1;
int main(){
 scanf("%d", &op1);

switch(op1) {
 case +:
    puts("ola");
}

}
```

Comment: Meu C tá enferrujado, mas tenta procurar os símbolos pelos correspondentes em char, por exemplo, `case #10`

Comment: Alguma das respostas resolveu o problema? Acha que pode aceitar uma delas? Veja o [tour] como fazer isso. Você estaria ajudando a comunidade identificando a melhor solução. Só pode aceitar uma delas, mas pode votar em qualquer coisa no site todo.

Answer (score 1):

Tem como fazer isso sim:

```
#include <stdio.h>

char op1;
int main() {
    scanf("%c", &op1);

    switch(op1) {
        case '+': puts("ola");
    }

}
```

---

Aspas duplas significam String, aspas simples significam Caractere, então é só colocar aspas simples e usar uma variável do tipo char.

Answer (score 1):

Isso simplesmente não é possível. Não pode colocar o que bem entender no `case`. Ali cabe apenas valores constantes primitivos. Sequer é possível usar um *array*, incluindo *strings*.

O que pode usar é:

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main() {
    char op1;
    scanf("%c", &op1);
    switch (op1) {
         case '+':
             printf("ola");
    }
}
```

Veja [funcionando no **ideone**](https://ideone.com/Oexbm2). E [no **repl.it**](https://repl.it/join/adriupmm-maniero). Também [coloquei no **GitHub** para referência futura](https://github.com/maniero/SOpt/blob/master/C/Syntax/CaseChar.c).

Aproveitei para organizar o código.

Answer (score 1):

Não sei se entendi direito a tua dúvida, mas se entendi bem é possível sim

Veja o código:

```
#include <stdio.h>
 
int main()
{
    char op;
    scanf(" %c", &op);
 
    switch (op) {
         case '+':{ printf("Hello World"); break; }
         /* outras opções */
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Na verdade é possível reconhecer pelo tipo char qualquer caractere que esteja na tabela [ASCII](http://ic.unicamp.br/%7Eeverton/aulas/hardware/tabelaASCII.pdf/%20ASCII). Dê uma olha, pode ser que seja apenas isso.

Repare que eu tive de utilizar uma variável do tipo `char` e não `int` para que desse certo. Neste caso o teu programa irá comparar com qualquer tipo de caractere, no caso o que tu busca é o caractere correspondente ao sinal de "+".

Note também que neste caso fiz uso de aspas simples, isso porque em C e C++ é entendido que aspas duplas são usadas para `strings`, que nada mais são que uma cadeia (ou vetor) de caracteres, já a aspas simples é entendida para caracteres mesmo.

Espero ter ajudado. :)